# Java Test with EasyMock

Tags: java, testing

I'm traying to make a test, and I have this

```
Analysis analysis = EasyMock.createMock(Analysis.class);
Request request = EasyMock.createMock(Request.class);
EasyMock.expect(analysis.request()).andReturn(request).anyTimes();
EasyMock.replay(request);
EasyMock.replay(analysis);
return analysis;
```

But I need to change this

```
EasyMock.expect(analysis.request()).andReturn(request).anyTimes();
```

for something similar to this

```
EasyMock.expect(request.entryValue("field")).andReturn(message).anyTimes();
```

but I can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question I can't understand if you omitted some lines. The syntax in the line with "anyTimes()" is correct, but Easymock doesn't work this way. It is supposed to be used in unit tests.

Stage 0. You insert/set mock objects into service/object you want to test.

```
public final IMocksControl mockControl = createStrictControl();
@Before
public void setup() {
    boxStatusRepoMock = mockControl.createMock(BoxStatusRepo.class);
    boxRepoMock = mockControl.createMock(BoxRepo.class);

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(boxService, "boxStatusRepo", boxStatusRepoMock);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(boxService, "boxRepo", boxRepoMock);
}
```

All the other code in stages 1-6 is to be put into a method with annotation @Test

Stage 1. You prepare data to be returned by mocked methods

Stage 2. You list expected calls of mock objects. The number and the order are important.

Stage 3. You call mockControl.replay();

Stage 4. You call some service method - the one which call mocks with their methods (you set them in stage 0). The service must not be a mock itself.

Stage 5. You call mockControl.verify();

Stage 6. Optionally you can check the value returned in stage 4.

[A tutorial on easymock](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/easymock/)